# Ruby Rails Simulate a Devise authed user in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This might be completely obvious but I'm not seeing it;

How do I go about making a user in a controller and authing that user entirely in the controller action just for display purposes?

I want to do something like;

```rb
fake_user = User.new
fake_user.auth! # or what ever to simulate it as if fake_user had logged in..
```

But I don't want the user to be saved to the database.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When you say that you want to "auth" the user, do you mean you're logging out the current user and logging in the fake user? Or do you mean your User model is `authorisable` and you want to flip that switch? The explanation sounds like the former, but that would surely break your user's experience.

Comment: Good question.  I don't want to auth the user.  I want to have a second user that is authed, but not a real user for testing purposes but not in rspec.  An actual place in the UI where we can test in real time what an unauthed user can do, an authed user without any permissions, and an authed user with permissions (the actual user).. This is a DEV only thing that only shows up on a dev server for information to my  QA team only.

Comment: Why, though, does this have to be a fake user? I'd normally do this by having one example of each user role set up for just this purpose. Adding the extra complication of a fake user just means there's more distance between the test and the real world.

Comment: Yeah I had wanted to just add a dummy user to the db that no one can login to but that might not be an option due to other aspects of the app.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that, if the user isn't saved to the DB, there are bound to be problems with parts of the app that try to load user details from the DB - a user-profile page or list of all users or something. Could you perhaps create a default scope for the User model that doesn't include your dummy users? Then they wouldn't be visible except when explicitly referenced.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to test I would just overwrite the `signed_in?` method on User and make it return true.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   def signed_in?
      true
   end
end
```

That way in your view you can ask `@user.signed_in?`